# Generalized execution time measurement across different architectures

Tags: python, c++, llvm, hardware, execution-time

Is there a way to measure the execution time of a C++ or Python program in terms which is uniform across multiple architectures irrespective of the system performance such as Memory size, cache etc.

For e.g., If my code runs on a 16GB RAM in 1 unit of 'effective execution time', then it should run on exactly 1 unit of 'effective execution time' on any other system irrespective of the system load or configuration. Even if the actual time it takes for running the program is very different.

One of the working alternatives for C++ is doing an instruction count by converting it to an intermediate LLVM, which isn't as far as I know possible with python since it's interpreted.

I've not been able to find out anything that uses a principle which can work over multiple languages.

Comment: You may be looking for a way of calculating _code complexity_, not execution time.

Comment: Not exactly. The execution time varies for different inputs. But the complexity does not.